# Tengo el siguiente error, que no puedo solucionar en el xml andorid studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Estoy haciendo un App en Android Studio y me arroja el siguiente error que parece ser un fallo al inflar la view en mi archivo XML pero no logro darle solución.

Este es el XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/main3"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@drawable/touch" />
```

Este es el error, eh indica que el erro esta en la linea 12 , pero no muestra en pantalla ninguna linea roja o advierte nada

```
05-26 11:14:16.761 29462-29462/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: chilegodive.godivechile, PID: 29462
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chilegodive.godivechile/chilegodive.godivechile.ScrollingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
```

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que, tal vez el layout que estás inflando tiene algún componente que entra en conflicto con otro. Si el activity no carga es probable que sea eso. Pero para darte más detalle mejor coloca algo de código del xml, el LayoutInflater y en que momento te lanza el error con el depurador.

Comment: @AngelManuelElias estoy trabajando con un scrollingActivity y el error es del <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Comment: Ayuda porfavor que mas necesita

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que en verdad esta pasando, era lo siguiente.
Las fotos que tenia cargada desde android directamente a la aplicación eran demasiado pesadas para ser cargadas con normalidad, la única solución fue cambiar las fotos por otras con menos tamaño

Comment: El error habla de una clase que no puede inflar en este caso AppBarLayout "Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" **con esto que mencionas tendrías problemas de memoria**.

Comment: A que te refieres, podrías ser mas especifico?

Comment: @UpsetGrade Debes mencionar al usuario con el @ para que le llegue la notificación, de otra manera no se entera de tu pregunta.